# Angle related to two vectors in matlab in range (0,2 pi)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I want to an angle related to two vectors

```
a=[1,0]
```

and another vector

```
b = [x,y].
```

I want the result to be between 0 and 2 pi. For example if b= [-1,-1 ] the answer is 5 pi/4, not -3pi/4 or 3pi/4. Is there anyway?
Any answer is highly appreciated.
I have tried below code but the answer is not in range [0,2pi].It is in [0,pi].

```
atan2(norm(cross(A,B)),dot(A,B))
```

Which A and B are 3 dimentional vector corresponding to a and b

Comment: Do you always assume `B` is later than `A` then?

Comment: No @AnderBiguri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mod` to force the result to be between `0` and `2pi`.

```
theta = mod(theta, 2*pi);
```

As far as getting the angle between the two vectors, there are two ways.

If you want the smallest angle between the two vectors you can use the dot product

```
theta = mod(acos(dot(a / norm(a), b / norm(b))), 2*pi);
```

If you want the *signed* angle between the two vectors you can use the above equation but also use the cross product to determine the sign

```
% Unsigned angle between the two vectors
theta = acos(dot(a / norm(a), b / norm(b)));

% Determine the sign of the angle
sgn = sign(cross([a, 0], [b, 0]));


% Apply the sign and use mod to make it between 0 and 2*pi
theta = mod(theta * (-1)^(sgn(3) < 0), 2*pi);
```

Comment: Where are a and b?

Comment: I tried  theta = acos(dot([1,0] / norm([1,0]), [-1,-1] / norm([-1,-1])));
>> theta = mod(theta, 2*pi) but it doesn't give 5pi/4

Comment: @saranj The code in your post doesn't work for me. Please update it so it actually runs. My answer computes the angle between the two vectors using the dot product. The angle it returns for those inputs is 3*pi/4 since that is the smallest angle.

Comment: @saranj As I said. The code *in your post does not run*. Please update it.

Comment: I know it is the smallest angle, but the answer I'm searching for is not the smallest angle. I want the answer to be 5 pi/4

Comment: @saranj The angle between 2 vectors is **the shortest angle** between them. This answer is good. Your definition is bad. Edit the question please

Comment: I edited the question. Could you help me, please? @AnderBiguri

Comment: @Suever I did it.

Comment: Yes, I really want to define the angle the way I've stated. Please delete first part of your answer, then I will choose it as correct nswer

Comment: @saranj deleting information helps no one. Leave as it is.

Comment: the code you wrote is not correct. please try to run it for a=[1,0] and b=[-1,0]. In this case, it returns 0 instead of pi

Comment: @saranj Updated.

Comment: @Suever the code you wrote is not correct. please try to run it for a=[1,0] and b=[-1,0]. In this case, it returns 0 instead of pi

Comment: @saranj I just said I updated it. Did you try to run it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily with **complex arithmetic**: consider each vector to be a complex number, compute its angle, subtract the two angles, and take the result modulo 2:

```
result = mod(angle(b*[1;1j]) - angle(a*[1;1j]), 2*pi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula:

f(x,y)=pi-pi/2*(1+sgn(x))*(1-sgn(y^2))-pi/4*(2+sgn(x))*sgn(y)

```
    -sgn(x*y)*atan((abs(x)-abs(y))/(abs(x)+abs(y)))
```